# How to position a button in a specific location of a background image HTML

Tags: html, image, css

[image]

I am new to HTML and CSS. I learned the basics from codeacademy, and there is a lot for me to learn. I started making a website using a template and began editing on Dreamweaver. 
One question that I had was about centering the button (in the attached image above) in the middle of the cell present in the background image. This will seem as if you are clicking on the nucleus of the cell to Enter the website. I am not exactly sure about how I would do that. I want to make sure that it is in the exact same position regardless of the browser/screen size that I have.
This is the CSS3 code for the background image and the button in the header:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("../../images/header.jpg");
    background-s[![enter image description here][1]][1]ize: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7.5em 0 2em 0;
    cursor: default;


#header .button {
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 100%;
        width: 4.5em;
        height: 4.5em;
        line-height: 4.5em;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.25em;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Comment: your background size is responsive and dictated by the browser (since you used center / cover) and anyways you want to dynamically realize where your "cell design" is and place the button in the same position? Is that right?...

Comment: Yes, so place the button in the middle of the cell. Is that possible?

Comment: If your "cell design" is placed let's say 10% below the center, when you resize the window, it'll always be approximately in that 10% top offset. Have you tried to : center your button and move it center + 10% top?

Comment: No I have not, and I am not exactly sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: All of the image I have referenced is not displayed. There is still a significant portion that is present, so if I were to shift the image down a little, wouldn't that work. But that would still change depending on the browser and size right?

Answer (score 0):

If the "bulb" element in the background image is located at 60%, so should be your button:

http://jsbin.com/misoco/2/edit?html,css,js,output

again, this is not perfect, it'll **work nicely on portrait** mode,
but as soon as you enter in landscape (gray top/bottom image lines start to disappear), the positions will not match any more exactly...
here you could listen for css3 `@media landscape` and apply a different %...

```css
html, body{height:100%;}
body{
  margin:0;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGzcs.png) 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

#at50top{
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
  height:3px;
  width:100%;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-1px;
}

#start{
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:0;

  position:absolute;

  top:60%; /* if circle bulb in image is at 60% set at 60% */
  left:50%;
  width:  100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top:  -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="at50top">I'm at 50% top</div>
<button id="start">I'm at 60%</button>
```